# Display result if Table names are the same due to INNER JOIN

Tags: php

I don't know how to Explain my problem so here it goes

1. I have a Table called asalink with codes linked to names in a table called asatbl
2. I'm joining the tables but need the same Field to Display twice due to a different key

Please see my code Maybe this explains it better

```
    $sele = "SELECT asatbl_1.asaName, asatbl_1.asaSurname, asatbl.asaName, asatbl.asaSurname, asalink.linkammount
FROM asatbl AS asatbl_1 INNER JOIN (asalink INNER JOIN asatbl ON asalink.asaid = asatbl.asaid) ON asatbl_1.asaSales_ref = asalink.asaSales_ref
WHERE asalink.asaSales_ref=1001";
    $result = mysql_query($sele);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>ASA Name</th> <th>ASA Surname</th> <th>Recipient Name</th> <th>Recipient Surname</th> <th>Amount</th></tr>";


    if($mak = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['asaName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['asaSurname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['asatbl_1.asaName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['asatbl_1.asaSurname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['li nkammount'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        //echo '<td><a href="deleteuser.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
```

as you can see I used asatbl_.asaName and asatbl_1.Surname but does not work

Thanks in advance for help

Regards

Comment: i believe it would be best if you `var_dump($row)` first and see how it structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alias for the field names in result:

```
SELECT asatbl_1.asaName as fld1, asatbl_1.asaSurname as fld2, ... and so on.
```

Then to retrieve data reference the alias in resultset

```
$row['fld1'] 
$row['fld2']
...
```

Hopes this helps

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with the way you are trying to get the values of the fields using `$row['asatbl_1.asaName']` and `$row['asatbl_1.asaSurname']`. You have to simply use `$row['asaName']` and `$row['asaSurname']` by removing table names before the column names.

After running any SQL query in PHP which has columns fetched along with table name using .(dot) through notations like - `SELECT **table_name.column_name** FROM table_name` you should not access the column values in the PHP query result with the table name prefixed to it which you are doing in `$row['asatbl_1.asaName']` and `$row['asatbl_1.asaSurname']`.